# Consume XML-SOAP web service from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

I have to consume a public service with the following properties - 
1. SSL is used as Transport Level Security.
2. User credentials are used for Authorization and Message Level security

> NOTE : Source Code is not available
>   for the service.

```
Sample URL - https://abc.com/SampleService/SampleService.svc
```

How do I consume from ASP.NET and call the exposed methods ?

Comment: Just use "Add Service Reference"

Comment: I get an error - Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: And what happens when you try to open that url in a browser?

Comment: "  Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage "

Comment: Did you try it with 'http' only? And where is that service from? Access can be disallowed as far as I know.

Comment: @SeeSharp: if IE can't open it, then you're not going to have any luck either. Work to get to the point where IE can open it, then work on "Add Service Reference".

Comment: @dampe/@John - It worked with 'HTTP', I added the Service Reference too. It generated the proxy class and I am able to instantiate too. Now when I try to connect it says invalid URI scheme - 'HTTP'. If I make it HTTPS, then it gives error - "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try right clicking at References folder and using "Add Service Reference" option? You can paste url there and it should discover service.
After this, you will get proxy of that service available and you will be able to instantiate it and call its method.

Comment: Will it discover even if it requires Authentication (username / password) ? I am not aware of SOAP services.

Comment: @SeeSharp: it should prompt if the service is requiring Basic authentication. Otherwise, you could fetch the WSDL using a browser and write it to disk, then point "Add Service Reference" to the file on disk. BTW, this isn't "discovery".